# DTDeviceKit: deviceType from {DEVICE_ID } was NULL

Tags: nativescript

I am getting really frustrated with this error. I am build an app using nativescript. The app use to run fine on my device but for some reason it stopped and I keep getting this error:

```
DTDeviceKit: deviceType from {DEVICE_ID } was NULL
[MT] DTDeviceKit: deviceType from {DEVICE_ID} was NULL
```

I tried building the app with Xcode and it successfully builds it and installs it on my device. Only when I try to install it with Nativescript I see the issue. 
I am using this command to install it `tns run ios --device="device_id_here" --hmr`

Any ideas what could be causing it?